# jquery javascript post of different classes to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to do a post in jquery to a MVC controller.
The problem is that I need to post data from 2 different classes:

here is the controller which should receive a single class entity and then a list of entities of another class

```
 public ActionResult Create(
            PAPER_OPERATION_PRODOTTI info,
            List<PRICING_PERIOD_EXT> pp_buy
            ){
...
```

Is this possible?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: getRootURL() + "/OperazioniPaperProdotti/Create",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(swap_all),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",



        success: function (result) {
            alert('im back');
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);

        }
    });
```

At the moment I'm passing to the controller an array where I'm putting all the data... it doesn't work

```
  var swap_all = new Array();

   ......

  var pricing_list = new Array();


    for (var c = 0; c < num_righe_to_update; c++) {


        var pricing = new Array();

        var id_to_op = "#ID_PRICING_PERIOD_" + c;
        var data_s_to_op = "#DATA_START_" + c;
        var data_e_to_op = "#DATA_END_" + c;
        var div_flag_op = "#FLAG_OP_ON_SAVE_" + c;
        var div_flag_linea = "#ID_LINEA_" + c;

        pricing = { 'ID_PRICING_PERIOD': $(id_to_op).val(), 'DATA_START_PREZZATURA': $(data_s_to_op).val(), 'DATA_END_PREZZATURA': $(data_e_to_op).val(), 'FLAG_OP_ON_SAVE': $(div_flag_op).val(), 'ID_LINEA': $(div_flag_linea).val() };
        pricing_list.push(pricing);

    }

    ......

    var swap = new Array();
    swap = {
            'ID_OPERAZIONE': $("#ID_OPERAZIONE").val(),
            'NUMERO_CONTRATTO': $("#NUMERO_CONTRATTO").val(),
            'BOOKING_COMPANY_CODE': $("#BOOKING_COMPANY_CODE").val(),
            'ID_CONTROPARTE': $("#ID_CONTROPARTE").val(),
            'DATA_CONTRATTO': $("#DATA_CONTRATTO").val(),
            'DATA_CHIUSURA': $("#DATA_CHIUSURA").val(),
            'MARKET_CODE': $("#MARKET_CODE").val(),
            'QUOTAZIONE_CODE': $("#QUOTAZIONE_CODE").val(),
            'UOM_PRIMARY': $("#UOM_PRIMARY").val()


    };

    swap_all.push(swap);
    swap_all.push(pricing_list);
```

How can I pass these data in the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are close.

```
var swap_all = {};
swap_all.swap = [];
swap_all.pricing_list = [];
swap_all.swap.push({
    ID_OPERAZIONE: $('#ID_OPERAZIONE').val(),
    ...
});
swap_all.pricing_list.push({
    field1: data,
    ....
});
```

you can set up the pricing list the same way.  I use this format and have a class defined on my controller with the same fields and this populates it.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt, at the moment I'm managing to pass to the controller the two classes once at the time, but the problem I'd like to pass both in the same post...

Comment: see my edit above.  using this format you should be able to send both classes

Comment: thank you Matt i've solved in a different way by defining a unique model the solution it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363007/how-to-pass-multiple-arrays-in-one-ajax-call-to-controller-method-asp-net-mvc-4